# Close popup and avoiding navigate to another page in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I use jQuery Mobile . I created one html file containing two pages (single file multiple page) . In page 2 I used a popup . When it closes , screen redirects to another page . How can I solve this issue ? I want when popup closed it remains in this page not redirecting to another page .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found.
Add `data-history="false"` to popup div. thus when popup closes it doesn't redirect to another page .

Comment: Saved my day! I got into this on iPhone (11.2) with Chrome only (FF, Safari are ok) all latest version, JQuery Mobile 1.45, tnx!